# How do I create a Lasso 9 Custom Error Page and email template

Tags: lasso-lang

In Lasso 8.x I created a customized error.lasso page in the LassoAdmin folder. I used the default error page template, plus some custom code at the end of the page to email me a copy of the error:

```
email_send(
    -to='test@example.com',
    -from='test@example.com',
    -subject='[Report] Lasso Error ' + response_filepath,
    -html=$__html_reply__
);
```

In Lasso 9, I can create a custom error page per the instructions on LassoGuide.com

http://lassoguide.com/language/error-handling.html?#error-reporting

> To define a custom error page, create a file named “error.lasso” and
>   place it in the root of the Web serving folder. Each host that has a
>   distinct web serving folder can have a custom error page.
>
> Custom error pages can be further fine-tuned by placing the
>   “error.lasso” file in the web serving folder’s subdirectories. Lasso
>   Server will process the first “error.lasso” it encounters on the file
>   path, starting with the current directory and continuing upwards until
>   it reaches the root of the web serving folder. If none are found,
>   Lasso Server will use the default error report.

What is the Lasso 9 equivalent of `$__html_reply__`? Is that a reasonable shortcut to coding a custom email template for error reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: [content_body](http://www.lassosoft.com/lassoDocs/languageReference/obj/content_body)

You may also find [error_stack](http://lassoguide.com/language/error-handling.html?highlight=error_stack#error_stack) useful

Answer (score 0):

As noted in Ke's concise response, content_body would be the most direct replacement.

The comment about the error_stack is a good reminder that the Lasso9 error stack is extremely useful, so if for some reason you do not want to include it in the web page itself, you would certainly want to include it in the email that gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at web_response->rawContent.
If setting, this completely overrides anything previously sent.
Otherwise will return the complete "to date" HTML chunk.

Not it can be used to both retrieve and set the raw HTML response.

http://www.lassosoft.com/lassoDocs/languageReference/obj/web_response/rawContent